# App component should place on top of all components in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to develop reactjs app with some components. 'App.jsx' have navigation bar. I want that navigation bar should be in front of all child components. When i try to use margins, its not working properly. Please help me. Thanks. Here i have code.

App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, NavLink, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home.jsx';
import Stuff from './pages/Stuff.jsx';
import Content from './pages/Contact.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
        <div>
            <ul className="header navigation" >
                <li><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
            </ul> 
            <div className="content">
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />                  
                <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff} />
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />            
            </div>                               
        </div>            
    </HashRouter>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Home.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';    

class Home extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div style={{ height:'100%', width:'100%', marginTop:-150 }}>
                <img src="./images/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style={{ width:'100%' }} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

By default, all child components are displaying on top of App component.

Comment: what is the expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You're header is displayed behind the rest because he's declared before the rest.

You can use `z-index` property as follow:

```
.header {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

---

I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve but maybe doing something like that could be better:

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0
}
```

**PS:** The rule `width:'100%'` in `{{ height:'100%', width:'100%', marginTop:-150 }}` is useless. A `<div>` is displayed as a block by default. It means that he will takes the whole width.